# Scala: Read an excel file and create output according to different templates methodology/pattern

Tags: java, excel, scala

On one hand I have coded a function in Scala that reads Excel Files. On the other I have different formats of reports: The first report will output certain informations, the second one will sum a few cells according to defined rules.

I struggle to model how those objects will interact together. What i have done for the moment is that the ExcelReader will take two arguments: a file input (filestream) and a trait for reports.

I was thinking to inject the report class and use the commmon trait createReport in the Excel Reader. Is it a good practice?

My other question is which object should i pass to this createReport method. Is it better to pass a List? an Array? I am not too sure which is the best object to model an excel sheet or if it is better to create my own object.

Thank you

Regards

Comment: It is useful to separate concerns. Have a function `File => ExcelData` for input, and others `ExcelData => ReportData1` for creating a data model, and finally renderers `ReportData1 => String`, `ReportData2 => Json`, etc. which can display/output the model data.

Comment: It makes sense, I am not too sure about how to store ExcelData. What kind of collection would you suggest, what would be the best implementation? thank you

Comment: Could you share your code example of reading excel file into some structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you interpret from Excel? It can be quite complex I guess, but for start you could try:

```
type ColIndex = String // maybe Int
type RowIndex = Int

sealed trait Cell
case class TextCell(text: String) extends Cell
case class NumericCell(value: BigDecimal) extends Cell
// maybe later if needed:
// case class FunctionCell(function: SomeExcelExpressionType) extends Cell

type ExcelData = Map[(ColIndex, RowIndex), Cell]
```

Comment: It is going to be mainly String and BigDecimal so your answer makes sense. Thank you very much.